# syntax error primary key during creating table after primary key

Tags: php

error in first line code during creating a table in MySQL
I created a table but there is an exception: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, mod' at line 1

```
    $newTable = "CREATE TABLE order (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            modelname VARCHAR(300),
            price INT(6),
            client VARCHAR(300),
            address VARCHAR(300),
 reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";
$conn->query($newTable);
```

Comment: You need to escape reserved words like order with backticks

Comment: order is reserved ?

Comment: _order is reserved ?..._ yes it is .. order by.. you have definitely heared of it

Comment: See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/ for the full list

Comment: Thanks ! I changed word and it works